# TSQL Group By Issue causing duplicates

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a query that I created which outputs projects as well as who is presenting the project. My issue is that I am trying to group the presenters to the project ID so it lists the presenters under the project ID and not include it multiple times.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @agendaID AS INT = '23';

SELECT 
   (SELECT att.empID,
           emp.firstName,
           emp.lastName,
           emp.ntid
    FROM   dbo.BS_ProjectReview_Attendees AS att
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.EmployeeTable AS emp
           ON att.empID = emp.EmpID
    WHERE  att.agendaID = @agendaID
    FOR    XML PATH ('attendee'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('attendees')),
   (SELECT pres.intID,
           int.intTitle,
           (SELECT emp.firstName,
                   emp.lastName,
                   emp.ntid
            FROM   dbo.EmployeeTable AS emp
            WHERE  emp.EmpID = pres.empID
            FOR    XML PATH ('presenter'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('presenters'))
    FROM   dbo.BS_ProjectReview_ProjectPresenters AS pres
    INNER JOIN dbo.BS_Initiatives AS int
    ON pres.intID = int.intID
    WHERE  pres.agendaID = @agendaID
    GROUP BY int.intID <----- ISSUE IS HERE
    FOR    XML PATH ('project'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('projects'))
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Here is my XML OUTPUT:

```
  <root>
<data>
<attendees>
  <attendee>
    <empID>1234</empID>
    <firstName>Mike</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <ntid>msmith</ntid>
  </attendee>
</attendees>
<projects>
  <project>
    <intID>202</intID>
    <intTitle>Infrastructure Expansion</intTitle>
    <presenters>
      <presenter>
        <firstName>Bob</firstName>
        <lastName>Jones</lastName>
        <ntid>bjones</ntid>
      </presenter>
    </presenters>
  </project>
  <project>
    <intID>202</intID>
    <intTitle>Infrastructure Expansion</intTitle>
    <presenters>
      <presenter>
        <firstName>User 1</firstName>
        <lastName>Last 1</lastName>
        <ntid>ulast1</ntid>
      </presenter>
    </presenters>
  </project>
</projects>
 </data>
</root>
```

Here is the desired output:

```
  <root>
<data>
<attendees>
  <attendee>
    <empID>1234</empID>
    <firstName>Mike</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <ntid>msmith</ntid>
  </attendee>
</attendees>
<projects>
  <project>
    <intID>202</intID>
    <intTitle>Infrastructure Expansion</intTitle>
    <presenters>
      <presenter>
        <firstName>Bob</firstName>
        <lastName>Jones</lastName>
        <ntid>bjones</ntid>
      </presenter>
       <presenter>
        <firstName>User 1</firstName>
        <lastName>Last 1</lastName>
        <ntid>ulast1</ntid>
      </presenter>
    </presenters>
  </project>
</projects>
 </data>
</root>
```

It should be listing both presenters under the same `intID` however its duplicating them.

I am getting an error with the group by clause as its not contained in an aggregate function and wants me to include `pres.empID` but then it would not make it unique as they are all different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure you need @ syntax.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483936/tsql-for-xml-explicit

Comment: That post doesn't seem to be related to my question at all. The issue is with the group by clause as I identified in the question.

Comment: Why don't you post the desired output

Comment: Updated the OP with the desired output.

Comment: @SBB, use INNER JOIN ( select distinct intID from dbo.BS_Initiatives)  AS int instead of INNER JOIN dbo.BS_Initiatives AS int

Comment: The issue isnt with the initiatives table though; its with ` FROM   dbo.BS_ProjectReview_ProjectPresenters AS pres`

Comment: @SBB, get distinct rows after joining those two tables , instead of  doing group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be solved using this, however, since SQLFiddle is down ATM, no example.

```
DECLARE @agendaID AS INT = '23';

SELECT 
   (SELECT att.empID,
           emp.firstName,
           emp.lastName,
           emp.ntid
    FROM   dbo.BS_ProjectReview_Attendees AS att
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.EmployeeTable AS emp
           ON att.empID = emp.EmpID
    WHERE  att.agendaID = @agendaID
    FOR    XML PATH ('attendee'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('attendees')),
   (SELECT pres.intID,
           int.intTitle,
           (SELECT emp.firstName,
                   emp.lastName,
                   emp.ntid
            FROM   dbo.EmployeeTable AS emp
                INNER JOIN dbo.BS_ProjectReview_ProjectPresenters AS pres ON emp.EmpID = pres.empID
            WHERE pres.intID = int.intID
            FOR    XML PATH ('presenter'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('presenters'))
    FROM   dbo.BS_Initiatives AS int
    WHERE  @agendaID IN ( SELECT pres.agendaID FROM dbo.BS_ProjectReview_ProjectPresenters AS pres WHERE pres.intID = int.intID)
    FOR    XML PATH ('project'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('projects'))
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```